# inheritance for an arraylist of quizQuestions

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, boolean

**Edit:
Thank you so much my program is finally running .**

I edit the code of the addChoice so that it reads a string of concatenated numbers and white spaces; I also modified the checkanswer method, but still whenever i type in the correct answer it counts it wrong , the following is my code

```
          public void addChoice(String choice, boolean correct){
      super.addChoice(choice, correct);
      if(correct == true){
           count++;
           choiceString +=   "" + count+" " ;
           answers.add(choiceString);
            }
       super.setAnswer(choiceString.trim());
     }            


     public boolean checkAnswer( String response )
   {
    super.checkAnswer(response);
    boolean ok = false;
    response = response.trim();
    String correctAnswers [] = response.split(" ");
    for(int i=0; i<correctAnswers.length;i++){
        if (answers.contains(correctAnswers[i]))
        { ok = true;}
        else
        {  ok=false;}
     }
    return ok;
   }
```

**My problem:**

For my question , the first and second options are correct .So, he user can input either 1 or 2 or 1 2 or 2 1 in order for him/ her to get a full score on the question; when I type any other option than the ones listed above I should revive a zero. So My issues is that my check answer method always return true for some reason so whatever I type, even if I type a wrong answer it counts it as true.So, I will need help with that part.

Thank you

Comment: This is **way** too much code. Narrow your code down to the relevant classes/methods please.

Answer (score 3):

You are always setting it to `true` here inside `AnyChoiceQuestion`.`checkAnswer`:

```
if(true)
     {ok = true;}
```

I think you meant to say:

```
if (answers.contains(correctAnswers[i]))
    ok = true;
```

Comment: I did that , but now checkanswer does not work correctly, whenever I type a correct answer fore example 1, 2 it returns false. What do you think is the error.

Comment: You are typing `Char Short` for the answer right?  Because that's what you're checking in `checkAnswer`, against the choice values themselves, not the indexes of the choices.

Comment: No actually I want to type the number of the choice so the input should be a single number  or multiple numbers separated by white space .For example; answer should be 1 or  1 2

Comment: Sure. That's not what your code is doing. You need to track the indexes somewhere and compare those instead of the values of the choices.

Comment: I edit the addChoice and CheckAnswer methods; you can find the code in my original post, but still my checkAnswer does not work correctly even after I implemented the changes you recommended. Can you till me what i am missing? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your issue lies in if(true), it will always fire. So answer will be true. I think you meant if (answers.contains(correntAnswers[i[)

Comment: I did that but know my method does not work correctly it returns false to all of my answer even if they are correct